# RSS / Atom feed is outputting encoded entities instead of quotes in titles

Tags: html-entities, rss

When publishing my Atom feed, quotation marks are being converted to HTML entities and being output without conversion back to the character.

Example:

Article title: `What's New Today!`

Output in Atom feed as: `What&#8217;s New Today!`

I created my Atom feed based off of the Atom feed examples in the EE documentation.

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is that the EE example feed encloses the title between CDATA tags, which instructs the feed reader to ignore any entities in that text and output it exactly as is.

The solution to this is to replace this:

`<title><![CDATA[{title}]]></title>`

...with this:

`<title>{exp:xml_encode}{title}{/exp:xml_encode}</title>`

Note that there are two places to do this if you're starting from the example feed. Also note that the "Agile Records" example feed *does* use the correct method, and it appears that the use of CDATA in the documentation example is an error.

Here's the forum post where I found this info: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/220237/